# Manipulating data from csv using pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

here is a question about the data from pandas. What I am looking is to fetch two column from a csv file, and manipulate these data before finally saving them.

The csv file looks like :

```
year    month
2007    1
2007    2
2007    3
2007    4
2008    1
2008    3
```

this is my current code:

```
records = pd.read_csv(path)
frame = pd.DataFrame(records)
combined = datetime(frame['year'].astype(int), frame['month'].astype(int), 1)
```

The error is :

```
TypeError: cannot convert the series to "<type 'int'>"
```

any thoughts?

Comment: i am pretty sure the file is csv. The above data is just an example of format. i then remove pd.DataFrame line. But the problem still remains....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

datetime won't operate on a pandas Series (column of a dataframe). You can use `to_datetime` or you could use `datetime` within `apply`. Something like the following should work:

```
In [9]: df
Out[9]: 
   year  month
0  2007      1
1  2007      2
2  2007      3
3  2007      4
4  2008      1
5  2008      3

In [10]: pd.to_datetime(df['year'].astype(str) + '-'
                     + df['month'].astype(str)
                     + '-1')
Out[10]: 
0   2007-01-01
1   2007-02-01
2   2007-03-01
3   2007-04-01
4   2008-01-01
5   2008-03-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Or use apply:

```
In [11]: df.apply(lambda x: datetime(x['year'],x['month'],1),axis=1)
Out[11]: 
0   2007-01-01
1   2007-02-01
2   2007-03-01
3   2007-04-01
4   2008-01-01
5   2008-03-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

**Another Edit**: You can also do most of the date parsing with `read_csv` but then you need to adjust the *day* after you read it in (note, my data is in a string named 'data'):

```
In [12]: df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data),header=True,                           
                          parse_dates={'date':['year','month']})
In [13]: df['date'] = df['date'].values.astype('datetime64[M]')                 
In [14]: df
Out[14]: 
        date
0 2007-01-01
1 2007-02-01
2 2007-03-01
3 2007-04-01
4 2008-01-01
5 2008-03-01
```

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue the answer is assuming that you have the Year, Month and Day in columns of your DataFrame:

```
df['Date'] = df[['Year', 'Month', 'Day']].apply(lambda s : datetime.datetime(*s),axis = 1)
```

first part selects the columns with the Year, Month and Date form the Dateframe, second bit applies the datetime function element-wise on the data.

if you do not gave the day in your data asit looks like form your data, just do:

df['Day'] = 1

to place the day there as well.   should be way to do that in code, but will be quick workaround.  Can always drop the Day column afterward if you dont want it.

Comment: Mmm. see someone posted simialr answer while I was typing this.  will leave for a while and delete later

Comment: Yeah, I did the `to_datetime` answer a while ago and the came back and added the `apply` answer at about the same time as you.

Comment: not a speedfreak myself, but i tested yours and my apply method.   Youe is about 50% faster as mine has the overhead of creating a new dataframe before doing the apply.   All in all your is probably better.  Also handles the 1 for day better than mine.